# Error while connecting to oracleXE11.2 from Squirrel

Tags: oracle, jdbc, runtime-error, squirrel-sql

I'm getting this error when I connect to oracleXe 11.2 from squirrel

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection
>   refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=186647040)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4))))

Comment: Try searching for ora-12505 and get your connection details fixed. The SID for an XE Database is mostly xe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look for [ORA-12505](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_12505_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_of_sid_given_in_connect_descriptor.htm) you will find that the message behind this number is that you SID in the connection descriptor is incorrect. This can have several reasons. The standard SID for an XE database is XE unless you did not change any of the listener.ora or tnsnames.ora. If you are able to connect to the database with SQL Developer or SQLPlus properly you should probably check the connection details you provided to Squirrel and edit them accordingly.

Comment: but i want to know how to fix this ,so please post the details if you have?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Squirrel. Somewhere you have to configure as which user you want to connect to which database. You can find some information here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0112.html (Connect to Oracle via JDBC) and here http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/squirrel-sql/wiki/GettingStarted (Connect with Squirrel to a database).

Comment: i resolved this issue by taking the help from this site:---- http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/squirrel-sql/wiki/GettingStarted ,so might be this site will helpfull to others who face the same issue .i deeply thanks to you for your quick reply.